# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field $stable of type I in class

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I get the following errors when trying to navigate to a Fragment that uses Material Motion.

**Versions used:**

- Kotlin 1.5.10
- Compose Beta 09
- Material 1.4.0-rc01
- Fragment 1.3.5
- AGP 7.0.0-beta03 (have to wait for Dagger fix)
- Accompanist 0.11.1

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field $stable of type I in class Landroidx/compose/animation/core/Transition; or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.compose.animation.core.Transition' appears in /data/app/~~NMhx8f3SifgkfcXt9VHSKg==/app.tempory.debug-ZA5ilk8Gd0enqUNaUHOpCg==/base.apk)
        at com.google.accompanist.imageloading.MaterialLoadingImage.updateFadeInTransition(MaterialLoadingImage.kt:53)
        at com.google.accompanist.imageloading.LoadPainterKt.animateFadeInColorFilter(LoadPainter.kt:382)
        at com.google.accompanist.imageloading.LoadPainterKt.access$animateFadeInColorFilter(LoadPainter.kt:1)
        at com.google.accompanist.imageloading.LoadPainterKt$animateFadeInColorFilter$3.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.accompanist.imageloading.LoadPainterKt$animateFadeInColorFilter$3.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2399)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2578)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:523)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2564)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2540)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:613)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:764)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:103)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:447)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:416)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I forgot to update Accompanist to the correct version (0.12.0) in this case.

Comment: When you self answer, mark your answer as the correct answer too, please, so that others may know that the question has been resolved

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow only allows this after 2 days.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I had no knowledge of this rule. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: Do you know why this happens when accompanist was older? Was it due to that bringing in an older compose compiler version and somehow introducing this bug?

Answer (score 5):

This wasn't OP's issue, but for people like myself who stumble here from searching, a similar error message can occur if you edit a class to be `@Immutable` in compose. This is a compiler cache error, and simply doing `Build -> Rebuild` from the Android Studio menu fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was the problem with the new update of the Material library. The last working version was:

```
   implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha03"
```

And it starts throwing the error after upgrading to:

```
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha04"
```

So I reverted, and the problem was solved.

Comment: (this worked for me)  
upgrade to the latest version so it can work for you: 
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha05"

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my Compose version from `1.4.0` to `1.5.0-alpha03` and it works now

```kotlin
object Compose {

    const val UI = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$COMPOSE"
    const val MATERIAL = "androidx.compose.material:material:$COMPOSE"

    const val TOOLING = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$COMPOSE"
    const val TOOLING_PREVIEW = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$COMPOSE"

    private object Version {
        const val COMPOSE = "1.5.0-alpha03"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case **clean & re-build** solved the issue